# Redirecting two Multisite domains to Single site on different host

Tags: multisite, redirect

We have **`Domain1.com`** and **`Domain2.com`** in a Wordpress Multisite. They're quite big in terms of content.

I want to redirect everything on `Domain1.com` and `Domain2.com` except the homepage to **`Domain3.com`** which is in a Single site installation on a different host.

The `htaccess` for Multi Site is site wide and I tried fiddling with some code but couldn't accomplish anything worth mentioning.

We also explored several plugins but they don't seem to do the job. The Redirection plugin fails on me when trying to do a bulk upload, and I also think it's not designed for WPMU.

Comment: Not enough information.  Does the homepage on domain1 and domain2 contain asset urls that link to domain1/2?  Does domain3.com contain the same assets?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the most graceful way of doing this, but you could setup a redirect using PHP, instead of using htaccess.

So you could do something along the lines of, just changing the Google URL to your other websites:

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) { } else { ?>
    <?php $websiteURL = 'http://www.google.co.uk';
    <?php header('Location: '.$websiteURL); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Let me know how you get on...

Comment: Is this a proper 301 redirect? We don't want to lose any SEO juice. Right now I redirect everything using Cloudflare, but Google is not accepting the 'change of address'. Also it redirects the homepage as well, which is not ideal.

Comment: They both do the same job, by redirecting the page, so I don't think this will have any impact on Google rankings.